# Returning a byte array from a C dll to C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, dll, dllimport

I'm trying to get a byte array from a DLL written in C in my C# program.  The DLL is used to communicate with a National Instruments USB-8451.  The function I'm trying to use returns the pointer to the array as an output parameter.  Most of the questions/answer I've found online for this type of issue have the function returning the pointer to the array (not using a parameter).

The function in c has the following prototype.

```
 int32 ni845xI2cWriteRead (
   NiHandle DeviceHandle,
   NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
   uInt32   WriteSize,
   uInt8 *  WriteData,
   uInt32   NumBytesToRead,
   uInt32 * ReadSize,
   uInt8 *  ReadData
   );
```

In C# I have following code to access the DLL.

```
[DllImport("NI845x.dll")]
public static extern Int32 ni845xI2cWriteRead(
        IntPtr DeviceHandle,
        IntPtr ConfigurationHandle,
        UInt32 WriteSize,
        byte[] WriteData,
        UInt32 NumBytesToRead,
        out UInt32 ReadSize,
        out IntPtr ReadData
        );
```

The following is code is what I'm using to access the ni845xI2cWriteRead function.

```
Int32 err = 0;
IntPtr ptrToRead = IntPtr.Zero;
err = ni845xI2cWriteRead(DeviceHandle, I2CHandle, WriteSize,WriteData,
      NumBytesToRead, out ReadSize, out ptrToRead);
byte[] rd = new byte[ReadSize];
Marshal.Copy(ptrToRead, rd,0, (int)ReadSize);
```

The problem I'm having is getting the ReadData array.  The ReadSize is returning correctly.  The byte array I get out seems to be fairly random.  Sometimes all zeros, sometimes has (incorrect) values and sometimes I get an access violation error.  I know that the command is correctly sending and receiving the data from the USB-8451 because I'm using NI I/O Trace so I can see the correct data going out and coming back.

What am I doing wrong?  I can't see it and this has been really frustrating.  Thanks.

Comment: This is purely a guess, but what happens if you define `ReadData` as `byte []` (since `out IntPtr` would be equal to `**`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andro, [you nailed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474245/returning-a-byte-array-from-a-c-dll-to-c-sharp#comment68193453_40474245).  Thank you!  Sigh of relief.  I had previously tried `out byte[] ReadData` and that did not work but had not tried just the `byte[] ReadData`.  The correct DllImport is below.

```
    [DllImport("NI845x.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 ni845xI2cWriteRead(
            IntPtr DeviceHandle,
            IntPtr ConfigurationHandle,
            UInt32 WriteSize,
            byte[] WriteData,
            UInt32 NumBytesToRead,
            out UInt32 ReadSize,
            byte[] ReadData    
        );
```